# Associated Product Ordering/Sorting

Tags: product, configurable-product

Just wondering - how are you meant to sort the order of associated products?
It seems that they are sorted by their "ID", from smallest to largest.

If you forget to add an associated product, for example an XS Variant, and then add it - this will appear at the end, after the XXL etc. Or if you add a US8 after you've already added US10, it will be in the order US9, US10, US8 etc

Any ideas? There isn't an ordering column that is obvious.

Comment: This isn't the answer, but apparently you need a "50" in order to comment?? What's up with that. Anyways, we have sorted the attribute properties in the order we want them to appear on the product page, but it's not working. They are still sorted by item ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the positions for the attribute values.

```
Catalog->Attributes->Manage Atributes.
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`Catalog` -> `Manage Category` -> `Select your category` -> `Then Click on Category Products Tab` -> Set the position in the last column `By default its 1`... you can set the numbers as from smallest to largest.

EX position 1 displays at position 1 and position 2 after that

Answer (score 1):

There are posts discussing a Magento 'bug' where the listing of options in configurable products is sorted by ID and not by the attribute sorting order.
I have successfully implemented both these modules. They only affect the product item page, not the category listing page which is still sorted by Id. If I get that fixed, I will post my solution.

See:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/48424/18509
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28867699/3376305

Answer (score 0):

The ordering can be changed.

1) `Goto Catalog>>Manage attributes`

2) `Select the attribute used for configuring configurable product`

3) `Go to options in there`

4) `Change the order from it.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change from manage attribute.

1) Admin->Catalog->attributes->Manage Attributes->Select Attributes->"**Position**" to all options.

2) Open Configurable Product from Manage Product . Remove all simple item which is currently Added and save item . Again open item add simple item by ordering which you need on front end,
Magento set order while adding simple item to any configurable.