# Magento 1.9.1 configurable product attribute sorting

Tags: configurable-product, sorting

As i already mentioned, there seems to be a problem with magento 1.9.1 and the sorting of attributes of configurable products.
The options of a configurable product now ALWAYS depend on the product ID of the simple product. The order of the attribute options are ignored.

I went back to magento 1.9.0.1. Maybe someone can determine how the sorting in 1.9.1 is done. It would be great for everyone who uses configurable products to fix that.

If somebody wants to see that, you can do it [here](http://installatron.com/magento/demo/hana-flat-charcoal) in magento demo store.
I wasnt able to sort the sizes correctly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Note:** It has been brought to my attention that this solution does not work for Magento 1.9.2. In order to save others wasted time I'd like to point this out at the top of this post. If I develop my own solution or find someone else's solution that works for 1.9.2 I will update this post at that time.

**Notice:** The solution laid out here extends a block class file in Magento's core library. I reviewed Magento's source code prior to this approach and determined that there was not a good event to observe to avoid this approach. If in a future version of Magento this sorting issue is resolved, you may undo these changes below simply by disabling the extension in it's app/etc/modules XML file.

**Step 1:** create the file **app/etc/modules/FirstScribe_CatalogOptionSortFix.xml**

Contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <FirstScribe_CatalogOptionSortFix>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </FirstScribe_CatalogOptionSortFix>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Note:** For step 2 and 3, create directories for these files as necessary. For example, you may already have the directory **app/code/local**, or you may not, depending on what extensions you have already installed on your site.

**Step 2:** Create the file **app/code/local/FirstScribe/CatalogOptionSortFix/etc/config.xml**

Contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento 1.9.1.0 has a bug in that the configurable options are sorted by
 * ID rather than position for the Configurable Product's front end view script.
 * This extension addresses this problem.
 *
 * @category    FirstScribe
 * @package     FirstScribe_CatalogOptionSortFix
 * @version     2014.12.15
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <FirstScribe_CatalogOptionSortFix>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </FirstScribe_CatalogOptionSortFix>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_type_configurable>FirstScribe_CatalogOptionSortFix_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable</product_view_type_configurable>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step 3:** Create the file **app/code/local/FirstScribe/CatalogOptionSortFix/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php**

Contents:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento 1.9.1.0 has a bug in that the configurable options are sorted by
 * ID rather than position for the Configurable Product's front end view script.
 * This extension addresses this problem.
 *
 * @category    FirstScribe
 * @package     FirstScribe_CatalogOptionSortFix
 * @version     2014.12.15
 */
class FirstScribe_CatalogOptionSortFix_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
{
    /**
     * @var Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
     */
    protected $_read;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_tbl_eav_attribute_option;

    /**
     * Composes configuration for js
     *
     * @version 2014.12.15 - Addition of this line:
     *    $info['options'] = $this->_sortOptions($info['options']);
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getJsonConfig()
    {
        $attributes = array();
        $options    = array();
        $store      = $this->getCurrentStore();
        $taxHelper  = Mage::helper('tax');
        $currentProduct = $this->getProduct();

        $preconfiguredFlag = $currentProduct->hasPreconfiguredValues();
        if ($preconfiguredFlag) {
            $preconfiguredValues = $currentProduct->getPreconfiguredValues();
            $defaultValues       = array();
        }

        foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
            $productId  = $product->getId();

            foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $productAttribute   = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                $attributeValue     = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
                if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId])) {
                    $options[$productAttributeId] = array();
                }

                if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue])) {
                    $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue] = array();
                }
                $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
            }
        }

        $this->_resPrices = array(
            $this->_preparePrice($currentProduct->getFinalPrice())
        );

        foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
            $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
            $attributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
            $info = array(
                    'id'        => $productAttribute->getId(),
                    'code'      => $productAttribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    'label'     => $attribute->getLabel(),
                    'options'   => array()
            );

            $optionPrices = array();
            $prices = $attribute->getPrices();
            if (is_array($prices)) {
                foreach ($prices as $value) {
                    if(!$this->_validateAttributeValue($attributeId, $value, $options)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $currentProduct->setConfigurablePrice(
                            $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent'])
                    );
                    $currentProduct->setParentId(true);
                    Mage::dispatchEvent(
                            'catalog_product_type_configurable_price',
                            array('product' => $currentProduct)
                    );
                    $configurablePrice = $currentProduct->getConfigurablePrice();

                    if (isset($options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']])) {
                        $productsIndex = $options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']];
                    } else {
                        $productsIndex = array();
                    }

                    $info['options'][] = array(
                            'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                            'label'     => $value['label'],
                            'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                            'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                            'products'  => $productsIndex,
                    );
                    $optionPrices[] = $configurablePrice;
                }
            }

            // CALL SORT ORDER FIX
            $info['options'] = $this->_sortOptions($info['options']);

            /**
             * Prepare formated values for options choose
             */
            foreach ($optionPrices as $optionPrice) {
                foreach ($optionPrices as $additional) {
                    $this->_preparePrice(abs($additional-$optionPrice));
                }
            }
            if($this->_validateAttributeInfo($info)) {
                $attributes[$attributeId] = $info;
            }

            // Add attribute default value (if set)
            if ($preconfiguredFlag) {
                $configValue = $preconfiguredValues->getData('super_attribute/' . $attributeId);
                if ($configValue) {
                    $defaultValues[$attributeId] = $configValue;
                }
            }
        }

        $taxCalculation = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');
        if (!$taxCalculation->getCustomer() && Mage::registry('current_customer')) {
            $taxCalculation->setCustomer(Mage::registry('current_customer'));
        }

        $_request = $taxCalculation->getDefaultRateRequest();
        $_request->setProductClassId($currentProduct->getTaxClassId());
        $defaultTax = $taxCalculation->getRate($_request);

        $_request = $taxCalculation->getRateRequest();
        $_request->setProductClassId($currentProduct->getTaxClassId());
        $currentTax = $taxCalculation->getRate($_request);

        $taxConfig = array(
                'includeTax'        => $taxHelper->priceIncludesTax(),
                'showIncludeTax'    => $taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax(),
                'showBothPrices'    => $taxHelper->displayBothPrices(),
                'defaultTax'        => $defaultTax,
                'currentTax'        => $currentTax,
                'inclTaxTitle'      => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Incl. Tax')
        );

        $config = array(
                'attributes'        => $attributes,
                'template'          => str_replace('%s', '#{price}', $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat()),
                'basePrice'         => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($currentProduct->getFinalPrice())),
                'oldPrice'          => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($currentProduct->getPrice())),
                'productId'         => $currentProduct->getId(),
                'chooseText'        => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Choose an Option...'),
                'taxConfig'         => $taxConfig
        );

        if ($preconfiguredFlag && !empty($defaultValues)) {
            $config['defaultValues'] = $defaultValues;
        }

        $config = array_merge($config, $this->_getAdditionalConfig());    

        return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($config);
    }

    /**
     * Sort the options based off their position.
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _sortOptions($options)
    {
        if (count($options)) {
            if (!$this->_read || !$this->_tbl_eav_attribute_option) {
                $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

                $this->_read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
                $this->_tbl_eav_attribute_option = $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_option');
            }

            // Gather the option_id for all our current options
            $option_ids = array();
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                $option_ids[] = $option['id'];

                $var_name  = 'option_id_'.$option['id'];
                $$var_name = $option;
            }

            $sql    = "SELECT `option_id` FROM `{$this->_tbl_eav_attribute_option}` WHERE `option_id` IN('".implode('\',\'', $option_ids)."') ORDER BY `sort_order`";
            $result = $this->_read->fetchCol($sql);

            $options = array();
            foreach ($result as $option_id) {
                $var_name  = 'option_id_'.$option_id;
                $options[] = $$var_name;
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

**Step 4:** If enabled, refresh Magento's "Configuration" cache type under System -> Cache Management of the admin panel.

**Extension overview**

1. Extend the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable class.
2. Add a method to sort options by their `position` value by pulling this info from the database.
3. Rewrite the getJsonConfig method to call our new function after having gathered the options for an attribute.

Comment: works fantastically and I'm glad the solution doesn't affect future upgrades - many thanks to you for a viable solution.

Comment: Hey @Meogi although it seems your fix is perfect for the attribute values, are we sure everything is in order for the product select boxes themselves? Noticed an issue with ordering these the way they are set within the attribute set. For example- we had "Color" dragged above "Size" within the attribute set, however 1.9.1 switched the two (ignored the ordering). The only way to fix that was editing the product itself, and dragging the order within the configurable. Maybe this was just a rogue product that was accidentally reordered manually previously?

Comment: @Joe If I'm not mistaken, dragging the attribute higher/lower in the attribute set does not affect the order they are displayed on the front end product detail page. Instead, you must go into Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes, find your attribute and edit the "Position" value. This will affect both the order that configurable attributes are displayed on the product page as well as layered navigation. The order of configurable options can be overridden on a per product basis as well, by navigating to the "Associated Products" tab in the admin, and dragging the attributes up/down there.

Comment: @Meogi this is only for Layered Navigation Block position, for when you enable "Use in Layered Navigation".

Comment: @Joe I see, well then I do not know how to change the default settings (maybe it always have been it's placement in the attribute set, I'm not sure). I can state that on a Magento 1.9.1.0 installation I was still able to set it to an order of my choice by clicking/dragging up/down in the "Associated Products" tab of the configurable product. Where they are listed between the quick-create form and the product grid at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks! Would be cool to have this extension in the community code pool and on GitHub ;)

Comment: Hi,
unfortunatly it doenst seem to work with 1.9.2 anymore.
Maybe you could get it working with 1.9.2, please.

Comment: @Reinsch have you tried disabling the extension I describe above, and seeing if scrowler's answer (another answer in this post) works? His solution seems to tackle the source of the problem.

Comment: I tried your solution and scrowlers. Both do not seem to work with magento 1.9.2

Comment: @Reinsch Thanks for the update. Unfortunately I do not have personal time to dig into this myself. I'm sure when the next project at work comes around that utilizes configurable attributes, I'll be forced to develop a solution then. When that time comes, I'll be sure to update my answer here for Magento 1.9.2.

Comment: Fantastic!! Works like a charm with 1.9.2.2

Comment: @vibhu Good to know thanks for reporting this. Interesting as I have had comments that it does not work in 1.9.2.0. I haven't had a chance to look into it myself what the differences are.

Comment: I'm using BCP and i tried few local codes fixes and extension also above code but non of them working and it always sort by attribute id value, any idea hot to sort using attribute label or price.

Answer (score 11):

Just to add my two cents, the other two answers did well to point me in fix's direction, but I thought I'd attack it at the source rather than the block presentation point.

You can achieve the same result by extending the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection` model's `_loadPrices()` method, which despite the name is where a change was made (presumably for performance) resulting in the attributes being ordered by ID rather than by relevance.

The change appears to have been made to avoid nested `foreach` statements, but in turn loses the correct order as well. This solution modifies the updated logic slightly to track the attribute options, then performs another loop based on the original order to actually do the adding.

Here's an adjusted walkthrough similar to [meogi's answer above](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/48424/14992):

---

## Step 1: Register a new module

*Note:* if you already have one, re-use an existing one.

```
# File: app/etc/modules/YourCompany_AttributeFix.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourCompany_AttributeFix>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </YourCompany_AttributeFix>
    </modules>
</config>
```

## Step 2: Create the module's configuration

```
# File: app/code/local/YourCompany/AttributeFix/etc/config.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourCompany_AttributeFix>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </YourCompany_AttributeFix>
    </modules>    
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_type_configurable_attribute_collection>YourCompany_AttributeFix_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection</product_type_configurable_attribute_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

## Step 3: Add the resource model extension

```
# File: app/code/local/YourCompany/AttributeFix/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
/**
 * Catalog Configurable Product Attribute Collection - overridden to re-enable the attribute option
 * sorting by relevance rather than by ID as changed in the Magento core class
 */
class YourCompany_AttributeFix_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection
{
    /**
     * Load attribute prices information
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection
     */
    protected function _loadPrices()
    {
        if ($this->count()) {
            $pricings = array(
                0 => array()
            );

            if ($this->getHelper()->isPriceGlobal()) {
                $websiteId = 0;
            } else {
                $websiteId = (int)Mage::app()->getStore($this->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();
                $pricing[$websiteId] = array();
            }

            $select = $this->getConnection()->select()
                ->from(array('price' => $this->_priceTable))
                ->where('price.product_super_attribute_id IN (?)', array_keys($this->_items));

            if ($websiteId > 0) {
                $select->where('price.website_id IN(?)', array(0, $websiteId));
            } else {
                $select->where('price.website_id = ?', 0);
            }

            $query = $this->getConnection()->query($select);

            while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
                $pricings[(int)$row['website_id']][] = $row;
            }

            $values = array();

            foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
                $productAttribute = $item->getProductAttribute();
                if (!($productAttribute instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $options = $productAttribute->getFrontend()->getSelectOptions();

                $optionsByValue = array();
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $optionsByValue[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
                }

                /**
                 * Modification to re-enable the sorting by relevance for attribute options
                 * @author Robbie Averill <robbie.averill@kathmandu.co.nz>
                 */
                $toAdd = array();
                foreach ($this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
                             ->getUsedProducts(array($productAttribute->getAttributeCode()), $this->getProduct())
                         as $associatedProduct) {

                    $optionValue = $associatedProduct->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());

                    if (array_key_exists($optionValue, $optionsByValue)) {
                        $toAdd[] = $optionValue;
                    }
                }

                // Add the attribute options, but in the relevant order rather than by ID
                foreach (array_intersect_key($optionsByValue, array_flip($toAdd)) as $optionValueKey => $optionValue) {
                    // If option available in associated product
                    if (!isset($values[$item->getId() . ':' . $optionValue])) {
                        // If option not added, we will add it.
                        $values[$item->getId() . ':' . $optionValueKey] = array(
                            'product_super_attribute_id' => $item->getId(),
                            'value_index'                => $optionValueKey,
                            'label'                      => $optionsByValue[$optionValueKey],
                            'default_label'              => $optionsByValue[$optionValueKey],
                            'store_label'                => $optionsByValue[$optionValueKey],
                            'is_percent'                 => 0,
                            'pricing_value'              => null,
                            'use_default_value'          => true
                        );
                    }
                }
                /**
                 * End attribute option order modification
                 * @author Robbie Averill <robbie.averill@kathmandu.co.nz>
                 */
            }

            foreach ($pricings[0] as $pricing) {
                // Addding pricing to options
                $valueKey = $pricing['product_super_attribute_id'] . ':' . $pricing['value_index'];
                if (isset($values[$valueKey])) {
                    $values[$valueKey]['pricing_value']     = $pricing['pricing_value'];
                    $values[$valueKey]['is_percent']        = $pricing['is_percent'];
                    $values[$valueKey]['value_id']          = $pricing['value_id'];
                    $values[$valueKey]['use_default_value'] = true;
                }
            }

            if ($websiteId && isset($pricings[$websiteId])) {
                foreach ($pricings[$websiteId] as $pricing) {
                    $valueKey = $pricing['product_super_attribute_id'] . ':' . $pricing['value_index'];
                    if (isset($values[$valueKey])) {
                        $values[$valueKey]['pricing_value']     = $pricing['pricing_value'];
                        $values[$valueKey]['is_percent']        = $pricing['is_percent'];
                        $values[$valueKey]['value_id']          = $pricing['value_id'];
                        $values[$valueKey]['use_default_value'] = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach ($values as $data) {
                $this->getItemById($data['product_super_attribute_id'])->addPrice($data);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

## Step 4: Clear your cache

---

**For reference**, the actual change to the core class in a `git diff` would be below (do not directly edit core files!):

```
diff --git a/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php b/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
index 135d9d3..4d2a59b 100644
--- a/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
@@ -254,6 +254,11 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection
                     $optionsByValue[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
                 }

+                /**
+                 * Modification to re-enable the sorting by relevance for attribute options
+                 * @author Robbie Averill <robbie.averill@kathmandu.co.nz>
+                 */
+                $toAdd = array();
                 foreach ($this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
                              ->getUsedProducts(array($productAttribute->getAttributeCode()), $this->getProduct())
                          as $associatedProduct) {
@@ -261,22 +266,31 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection
                     $optionValue = $associatedProduct->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());

                     if (array_key_exists($optionValue, $optionsByValue)) {
-                        // If option available in associated product
-                        if (!isset($values[$item->getId() . ':' . $optionValue])) {
-                            // If option not added, we will add it.
-                            $values[$item->getId() . ':' . $optionValue] = array(
-                                'product_super_attribute_id' => $item->getId(),
-                                'value_index'                => $optionValue,
-                                'label'                      => $optionsByValue[$optionValue],
-                                'default_label'              => $optionsByValue[$optionValue],
-                                'store_label'                => $optionsByValue[$optionValue],
-                                'is_percent'                 => 0,
-                                'pricing_value'              => null,
-                                'use_default_value'          => true
-                            );
-                        }
+                        $toAdd[] = $optionValue;
                     }
                 }
+
+                // Add the attribute options, but in the relevant order rather than by ID
+                foreach (array_intersect_key($optionsByValue, array_flip($toAdd)) as $optionValueKey => $optionValue) {
+                    // If option available in associated product
+                    if (!isset($values[$item->getId() . ':' . $optionValue])) {
+                        // If option not added, we will add it.
+                        $values[$item->getId() . ':' . $optionValueKey] = array(
+                            'product_super_attribute_id' => $item->getId(),
+                            'value_index'                => $optionValueKey,
+                            'label'                      => $optionsByValue[$optionValueKey],
+                            'default_label'              => $optionsByValue[$optionValueKey],
+                            'store_label'                => $optionsByValue[$optionValueKey],
+                            'is_percent'                 => 0,
+                            'pricing_value'              => null,
+                            'use_default_value'          => true
+                        );
+                    }
+                }
+                /**
+                 * End attribute option order modification
+                 * @author Robbie Averill <robbie.averill@kathmandu.co.nz>
+                 */
             }

             foreach ($pricings[0] as $pricing) {
```

[This is also on GitHub](https://github.com/robbieaverill/magento-attribute-option-order-fix/tree/master) if anyone wants it for reference.

*Edit:* I've also [logged this as a bug with Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/941).

Comment: Awesome contribution my friend. +1 (yeah, not supposed to use these comments to say thanks but you killed it so I have to haha)

Comment: I tried it with magento 1.9.2 - doenst seem to work unfortunatly.
And I dont understand why this bug is still not fixed by Magento.

Comment: Have you ensured that your module is configured correctly? I'm sure they are aware of it, but it's probably something that would take time to verify before they release a patch since its a very important part of the system. *Edit:* You could also test the fix directly (and temporarily) but copying the patch directly in to the core class (temporarily)

Comment: @Reinsch I've just had an email from someone regarding incompatibility with CE 1.9.2 - have pushed an update to [my Github repository](https://github.com/robbieaverill/magento-attribute-option-order-fix) and tested it on CE 1.9.2 with Magento sample data and it's working correctly now

Comment: @RobbieAverill Does your fix also fix it in the admin panel associated products tab? That was where I noticed the bug (sorting by id vs attribute option position)

Comment: @MaierB you'd have to check, but I would assume that yes it would as it is addressing the issue at the lowest point.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - thats why I think your solution is the more acceptable (and correct) solution. Going to try it with EE 1.14.2.1 , will let you know if it works :)

Comment: @MaierB cheers - it works for me on 1.14.2.1, but my set is also full of a bunch of other junk :)

Comment: Great work @RobbieAverill - thanks very much. Tested and confirmed working on a Magento 1.9.2.1 website.

Comment: Disclaimer - there have been a couple of bugs with this code, including swatch incompatibility - check my GitHub repo for the latest stable release

Comment: @RobbieAverill Any chance of seeing a version of this that works with PHP 5.3?  I like seeing the new PHP features being used, but right now I don't have any option, our site is running on 5.3.24.

Comment: Hey @SenorPuerco in my GitHub repository I've used traits which require 5.4+ unfortunately. You can use the code in this answer, however you may come across some inconsistencies. That being said, I'm currently still using this answer's code in my production environment and haven't noticed any problems with it (although haven't been testing for them). See the issues register in my GH repo for a list of what they can be.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize that only the github code required 5.4.  I'll give this a shot.

Comment: @SenorPuerco cool- also you could try a tag on GH before I removed 5.4 support

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a proper fix but it's what I've done temporarily to avoid having to go back to 1.9.0.1 until the next Magento release hopefully fixes the issue properly. It will sort the option values alphabetically, you could of course sort by anything you want but I don't know how to access the sort order set in the backend and alphabetically is good enough for my purposes.

Change the file

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/configurable.php
```

Change line 215

```
if($this->_validateAttributeInfo($info)) {
   $attributes[$attributeId] = $info;
}
```

to

```
usort($info['options'], function ($a,$b)
    {
        return strcmp($a['label'],$b['label']);
    }
);
if($this->_validateAttributeInfo($info)) {
   $attributes[$attributeId] = $info;
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer for an answer which appropriately extends Magento's core library rather than modifying it directly. Still, kudos to Steve for this answer as it greatly helped me with knowing where to start to develop the solution I came up with.

Comment: Excellent worked like charm in Enterprise even thanks a ton you save my day..