# Super Attribute Position on Product Page Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

Hello Good Day to All

I have Attribute "Malakas","Mahina","Payat"

On a Product Page it will Show

```
Malakas
--Choose an Option--
Mahina
--Choose an Option--
Payat
--Choose an Option--
```

Is this a way to change the Postiton of Super Attribute so the Attribute "Payat" will be first ??

```
Payat
--Choose an Option--
Malakas
--Choose an Option--
Mahina
--Choose an Option--
```

I already try the Position and still not working on product view Page only the Left side bar is working for Postion

the Option Drag and Drop while Create product can be use but is there a way to make it default attribute

or is there a ways to change the code on the configurable Product Option so to use Attribute Position ?

Thank

Comment: you can check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45396/magento-1-9-1-configurable-product-attribute-sorting/76090 this might help you

Comment: which specific magento 1.9 version you are using?

Comment: @magefm I'm using the latest one 1.9.4.0 it seems the link that you give for me is for the sorting of Attribute( the choose option )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I check the magento collection.php thank you @magefms

```
    /**
     * Set order collection by Position
     *
     * @param string $dir
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection
     */
    public function orderByPosition($dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
    {
        $this->setOrder('position ',  $dir);
        return $this;
    }
```

Lucky for me my Attribute created at the same time so i achieve what i want 
Ijust change

```
  public function orderByPosition($dir = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this fix:
Copy the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
```

to local folder

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
```

> Please add the following code in line 305

```
$sortOrder = 1;
foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
$productAttribute = $item->getProductAttribute();
if (!($productAttribute instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract)) {
Continue;
}
$options = $productAttribute->getFrontend()->getSelectOptions();
foreach ($options as $option) {
if (!$option['value']) continue;
                    if (isset($values[$item->getId() . ':' . $option['value']])) {
                            $values[$item->getId() . ':' . $option['value']]['order'] = $sortOrder++;
                    }
            }
}
usort($values, function($a, $b) {
return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
});
```

The code given should be placed above the code of Magento shown below:

```
foreach ($values as $data) {

$this->getItemById($data[‘product_super_attribute_id’])->addPrice($data);

}
```

After the above changes, clear the cache and check if it works.

Comment: Hi magefms thank you for your help still the same the position of super attribute  "Malakas","Mahina","Payat" still same is there a way the magento use position so if i save Payat - Position 1 and Malakas as postion 2 and Mahina for position 3 so i will show like this

Comment: you can set it in `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes >`

Comment: hi magefms thank you for your answer but i believe the position is only work at the left side filter not on the Product view page